# Is there a way I can soundproof an exterior apartment door from outside noise?

Tags: doors, sound-proofing, noise-reduction

Its made of steel but hollow (though I'm not sure if completely hollow or if it has divisions like cells) with zero sound absorption.

I already weatherproofed it with foam strips, but even then every time someone walks or talks in the hallway outside I can hear everything, can even hear noises from other apartments that escape through their doors (which are the same) and enter mine.

Any way I can soundproof my door? I don't care about aesthetics but note that I can't modify anything on the outside-side of the door because its against the building rules. So whatever I do has to be inside the actual door or on the interior-side.

Answer (score 2):

You could try an acoustic curtain.

You could build an interior door to make your exterior door more like an air lock and then sound proof that door/wall to your hearts content.

Comment: +1 for thinking of an air lock. Also, check to see if there are switches or outlets on the common wall. Sound could be coming through the wall at those locations too.

Comment: Might try the curtain, or even an acoustic blanket.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the sound getting through doors is the result of small gaps. If you have taken care of that, FOR SURE, then you are most of the way there. One large often overlooked aspect however is the door seal on the bottom against the threshold, because the door needs to open over carpet or something. So to facilitate a good soundproof seal, you have to use an automatic door bottom seal, a type that raises up when you open the door, but seals tight against the floor or threshold when closed.

If you have already done that, and you are confident that the steel door is acting as a sounding board, you can deaden that effect by filling the interior with foam. but this can be very tricky if you don't know what the interior is like, it pretty much has to be completely hollow for that to work. If there is any kind of honeycomb like structure inside, you are stuck.

Don't waste your money on the foam egg crate material, it doesn't BLOCK sound coming through a solid wall or door, it would ABSORB sound emanating from INSIDE of your apartment. As mentioned there are heavy pads that can be hung / attached to the inside of the door that can help deaden the sound coming through. The best kind have foam on one side that goes against the door, then a rubber coated lead sheet on the side facing into your room. The foam absorbs the vibrations from the door, but the lead stops them from re-transmitting.

By the way, FOAM weather proofing strips to NOT block sound transmission. You need the more solid type. If foam blocked sound, why would they put in on the front of speakers or use it as covers for ear pieces?

Comment: By foam you mean polyurethane expanding foam? you know the yellow stuff in a spray can. I heard I could use styrofoam pellets and that it might be a better option than the foam. As for the foam+rubber sheet that would be hard to slide inside, the door is hollow but the areas that contain the lock mechanisms (2) are in compartments and I can't get a blanket in those spaces. The foam or pellets could be shoved there tho.

Comment: Not inside, on the outside (skin) of the door, INSIDE of your apartment.

Comment: Understood, I will try that and see how it goes.